# What does "Fix-it applied, fixed expression was:" mean?

Tags: date, swift3, nsdate, lldb

```
(lldb) po Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))
▿ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : -978307200.0

(lldb) po Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))!
▿ 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : -978307200.0


  Fix-it applied, fixed expression was:
    Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))
```

Why does `TimeInterval(0)` need to be fixed? I know zero means 1970-1-1, and the `init(timeIntervalSince1970:)` does not return an optional Date like `init?(xxx:)`:

```
/// Returns a `Date` initialized relative to 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 by a given number of seconds.
    public init(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TimeInterval(0` is not the problem, but the final exclamation mark
in

```
(lldb) po Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))!
```

As you noticed yourself, `init(timeIntervalSince1970:)` does not return
an optional, and therefore you cannot unwrap it. lldb "automatically"
fixes that by removing the exclamation mark, which is the "Fix-it"
offered by the compiler, i.e. the same which would be suggested
in the Xcode source editor for

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))!
```

[image]